# Chat window popup not opening in WebView on the same page

Tags: android, android-webview

> This is my code snippet.Whenever I click on the chat popup button ,the WebView goes out of view and black screen displays

```
         @Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    webView.removeAllViews();
    WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    webView.addView(webview);
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(webview);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add one more webview client along with your custom webview client as well as along `WebChromeClient`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```